# Perl substitution example from Mastering Regular Expressions book not working for me

Tags: regex, perl

I'm probably just missing something simple but the `s///` isn't assigning the changed string to my variable.  I try a more simple `s///` and it does work.

This example should trim the any digits after the decimal if there are more than three.

```
my $price = 12.34567;
print "$price\n";
$price =~ s/(\.\d\d[1-9]?)d*/$1/;
print "$1\n";           # This is printing .345 correctly.
print "$price\n";       # This should be 12.345 but is unchanged.

my $story = "dog";
$story =~ s/(do)g/$1/;
print "$story\n"; # This works.  It's changed to "do"
```

Edit: If the third digit is a zero it should trim it after two digits.

"Prettifying a stock Price:
...always take the first two digits after the decimal point, and take the third digit only if it is not zero. Then, remove any other digits.

Comment: Should be `\d` instead of `d`.

Comment: Besides the missing backslash, the RE doesn't look right -- what output do you expect for `12.340123`?

Comment: That was it.  Thank you @Benjamin W.

Here's the regex from the book:
![book excerpt](https://imgur.com/a/fy3zk)

Comment: O'Reilly ebooks often mess up source code, in my experience with them. I always double check the PDF version when in doubt (and it's available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substitution is wrong.

```
$price =~ s/(\.\d\d[1-9]?)d*/$1/;
```

should be

```
$price =~ s/(\.\d\d[1-9]?)\d*/$1/;
```

Your own version matches because `d*` can match an empty string, which it does because there are no `d` characters after the third decimal place

It seems odd to insist that any third decimal digit must be non-zero. So `0.00` is fine, but `0.000` is not, and will be truncated to the former. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Thank you that was it

![book image](https://imgur.com/a/fy3zk)

 “Prettifying a Stock Price
  
always take the first two digits after the decimal point, and take the third digit only if it is not zero. Then, remove any other digits.”

Comment: This is a [known erratum](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596528126#page81). If you read a technical book, IETF RFC or similar, it is always a good idea to check for errata.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you missed only a backslash before the last "d".

Change the first substiturion instruction to:

```
$price =~ s/(\.\d\d[1-9]?)\d*/$1/;
```